# How to determine if a categorical variable affects an independent variable?

Tags: r, feature-selection

I am looking at the `wine` dataset from the R `FactoMineR`package to find out whether the categorical variable soil type affects the feature set. Basically there are four distinct soil types and 29 different features and there are 20 observations

```
obs soil f1 f2 ... f29
  1    1 11 87 ... 20
  .    .  .  . ...  .
  7    2 13 10 ... 10
  .    .  .  . ...  .
 15    3 77 53 ... 54
  .    .  .  . ...  .
 20    4 88 81 ... 21
```

Given that I cannot use ANOVA or logistic regressions what other ways are there to figure out if the soil type affects the features? I am considering using box plots for visual inspection, but 29 box plots seems like a bit much. Are there any succinct plot types that could give me this kind of information?